# I would like to know how to remove old custom variables from GTM results

Tags: google-tag-manager

I would like to know how to remove old custom variables from GTM results.

I have updated custom variable on GTM console, but variables of old version still remain in the results.
I need to remove them from the result sets as they are causing troubles in my program.

If possible, please let me know the cause(maybe some sort of cache?) so that I can avoid further trouble.

Custom variables set in GTM are thrown to the cloudFront beacon and processed as a log to S3.
When the custom variable is changed, the result with the old variable remains in S3.

below code is defined in GTM

```
function() {
  return function(model) {
    var userID = {{user ID}};
    if(userID == '') {　
        userID = 0;  
    }
    var actionEvent = {{event}}; 
    var elementId = {{Click ID}}; 
    var element = {{Click Element}};
    var elementTagName = element.tagName; 
    var elementClasses = {{Click Classes}};
    var ancestorsClasses = '[' + elementClasses + ']';
    var loopIds = '[' + element.getAttribute('data-loopid') + ']';
    var parentElement = element.parentElement;

    while (parentElement && parentElement !== document.body) {
        ancestorsClasses = '[' + parentElement.className + ']_' + ancestorsClasses;
        loopIds = '[' + parentElement.getAttribute('data-loopid') + ']_' + loopIds;
        parentElement = parentElement.parentElement;
    }

    var clickText = null;
    if(elementTagName == 'A' || elementTagName == 'BUTTON' || elementTagName == 'SPAN') {
        clickText = {{Click Text}}; 
    }

    var ariaLabel = element.getAttribute('aria-label');


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var webBeaconUrl = '' //ここでcroudFrontのビーコンを設定
    var sendActionDatalog = 'test'

     xhr.open('GET', webBeaconUrl + '?' +sendActionDatalog, true);
     xhr.send(null);
    };
}
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear (GTM does not store any results). Do you mean you changed the definition for a variable? You need to publish your change to take effect, and if you have been in preview mode while publishing the change you will still need to hit "refresh". Maybe you can describe your problem with a little more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I add more detail.